# I have trouble understanding exponential time complexity

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

To begin with, here is the main code

```
 var fib = function(n) {
    if (n===0) return 0
    if (n===2 || n===1) return 1
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
};
```

so the question is to print the Fibonacci number, Now letting go of the logic of the question, I can see that whenever we increase the variable n by 1, the function will be called **2 * n** times, so even when we consider backtracking of the function by returning the variables it would be **4 * n** major operations, and according to the definition of exponential times time complexity, the number of operations should double every time we increase the input variable and I think it is not the case in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the naive Fibonacci implementation we do indeed find exponential time complexity (or more exactly O(2^n)), most readily apparent by looking at a tree graph of the function calls.

```
        F_5
   /          \
  F_3         F_4
/    \      /    \
F_1  F_2   F_3   F_2
          /   \
        F_2   F_1
```

You can clearly see how the number of execution doubles in each line (1, 2, 4,...)

To convince yourself, draw this diagram for `F_6` (and `F_7` if needed).

> definition of exponential times time complexity, the number of operations should double every time we increase the input variable

No, exponential time complexity means O(b^n), where n is the length of the input variable. It only doubles each time if `b=2`. However, you can have `b=3` (triples every time), `b=4` (quadruples) or `b=1.2213`, you get the point.

We can also write code that counts it for us:

```
var counter = 0;

function fib(n){
    counter++;    
    if( n <= 1 ){
        return 1;
    }
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}

for( var i = 0; i < 15; ++i ){
    counter = 0;
    fib(i);
    console.log("Fib evaluations for " + i + ": " + counter);
}
```

If you do a logarithmic plot of the counter you get the following picture, confirming the exponential increase in execution time:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Today I really learned a lot.

Comment: It doesn't double and O(2^n) isn't tight.

Comment: @KellyBundy care to elaborate?

Comment: I just read on it, and a better upperbound is indeed (1+sqrt(5))/2. I will work it in.